# Should the order of direct2d push/pop axis aligned clips be reserved with push/pop layers

Tags: c++, winapi, direct2d

In direct2d there are two types of clips: axis aligned clips used with `PushAxisAlignedClip` and `PopAxisAlignedClip` and layer clips used with `PushLayer` and `PopLayer`. The docs say that the each call to `PushAxisAlignedClip` must be matched with a call to `PopAxisAlignedClip` and the same for `PushLayer` and `PopLayer` but I didn't find anything regarding the order of push/pop when using both clips.

What I want to do is to save the current rendering state and push some clips using `PushAxisAlignedClip` if the rectangle has no round corners and `PushAxisAlignedClip` if the is any round corners and when I finish, I pop all the clips using `PopAxisAlignedClip` and `PopLayer`.

I think of two methods to pop the layers:

1- On each push I store a flag to remember whether it was an axis aligned clip or a layer and iterate the flags in reverse order when going to pop. a good example for this flags store is `std::vector<bool>`

2- Have to counters one for aligned axis clips and one for layers and increment on push. When popping I will call `PopAxisAlignedClip` times the aligned clips counter and `PopLayer` times the layers counter.

I'm asking about the second method because I will not have to maintain a state of flags to track the type of pushed layers. Must the order of aligned clips be reserved with the order of layers? In other words, can I use something like this demonstrating code:

```
render_target->PushAxisAlignedClip(...)
render_target->PushLayer(...)
// some drawing code
render_target->PopAxisAlignedClip(...)
render_target->PopLayer(...)
```

Comment: Please move the last edit into the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the second way and it gave me the following `HRESULT` error from `EndDraw`: 0x88990014 which maps to `D2DERR_POP_CALL_DID_NOT_MATCH_PUSH` and the docs explains:

> The application attempted to pop a layer off the stack when a clip was at the top, or pop a clip off the stack when a layer was at the top.

So the answer to the question is: Yes the order of clips and layers must be reserved

EDIT: It is well documented here [PushAxisAlignedClip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-pushaxisalignedclip(constd2d1_rect_f__d2d1_antialias_mode)):

> A PushAxisAlignedClip and PopAxisAlignedClip pair can occur around or within a PushLayer and PopLayer, but cannot overlap. For example, the sequence of PushAxisAlignedClip, PushLayer, PopLayer, PopAxisAlignedClip is valid, but the sequence of PushAxisAlignedClip, PushLayer, PopAxisAlignedClip, PopLayer is invalid.

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted. This could help others who might have the same issue.